# jQuery UI resizing to controlled area

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, resize

I am trying to create 4 div sections (side-by-side) that expand across the width of the screen. I am using jQuery UI's resizable() feature to make a div wider or narrower. The problem is that if I make the "blue" div larger then it pushes the "green" div away. I want all four divs to always be visible and the green to not be pushed out.

Actually...just how jsBin is setup. Try resizing the "javascript" area all the way to the right - notice the "Output" does not leave the area. How do I go about achieving this?

see jsBin --> http://jsbin.com/tejahili/1/edit?html,css,js,output

HTML

```
<div id='wrapper'>

  <div id='yellow' class='box'></div>
  <div id='red' class='box'></div>
  <div id='blue' class='box'></div>
  <iframe id='green' class='box'></iframe>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}

.box {
  display:inline-block;
  width:24%;
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: `"Output"` means the `<iframe>` ? The fifth box at the bottom ?

Comment: Turn on "HTML", "CSS", "Javascript", and "Output". Leave "Console" off